# compression in openssl

Tags: ssl, compression, openssl

I want to see how `openssl` compresses the data and send it to SSL server.
I tried looking into Openssl code but I did not understand it.

Basically, I want to write simple client program and then send compressed data to SSL server.
I have already build a simple client which can connect to the server.

Any tips? how can do it?

Comment: Compression is optional part of TLS 1.1 protocol and is done in TLS code.

Comment: Don't:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME

Answer (score 4):

To make compression work with OpenSSL, the following points needs to be taken care:

1. OpenSSL library should be built without the macro OPENSSL_NO_COMP
2. If you are running on linux where zlib is present, the macro ZLIB_SHARED must also be enabled
3. While using the OpenSSL Library, you can call SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods() function which will load the built-in compression methods.
4. If you want to load your own compression method, then use SSL_COMP_add_compression_method() function.

Ensure that you are using the latest [OpenSSL version](http://www.openssl.org/source/).

More info on compression and the method SSL_COMP_add_compression_method can be obtained from [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_COMP_add_compression_method.html).

Comment: Link is broken.  Openssl.org changed links for ALL of their documentation.  Try:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_COMP_add_compression_method.html

Comment: @EricBolinger, I have fixed it.